# Parking a camper near Barcelona

Tags: automobiles, barcelona, campers

I plan to visit Barcelona next month in my camper, but want to sleep (Airbnb) in the city for a couple of nights. Has anybody suggestions where I can cheaply park my camper within easy train (or bus/tram/metro) reach of the city, but with minimum chance of theft/break-in? It is a small bus-camper (Mercedes Marco Polo), thus probably attractive to thieves, and is fitted with an alarm system. Size is 4.75 metres long, 2 metres high (fits in a normal parking spot).

I don't want to have to pay for an official camp-site (most are full anyway). The ideal would be a free car-park opposite police and railway stations (;-).

Comment: How big is the van? Would it fit in a normal parking spot?

Comment: Easy free parking, train station and police station are three requirements unlikely to be met in the same spot. Since most train and police stations are in urban areas, it's hard to park close to them. Anyway, for easy parking near a train I'd recommend Viladecans station because it's near Barcelona (less than half an hour train trip) but it's not in the centre of Viladecans - it's more in the industrial area - and it should be easy to park there, specially in august. Another option is to search for a non free truck parking - probably cheap and somehow guarded.